# A number relatively prime to n in the integers mod n produces all the elements

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Say that two integers $a,n$ are coprime. Then $r[a]_n$, where $[a]_n$ denotes the equivalence class of $a$ in the integers mod $n$, generates all the equivalence classes for the values $0<r<n+1$. Is there a theorem or proof for this? For example,

$r[3]_7$ generates $[3]_7, [6]_7, [2]_7, [5]_7, [1]_7, [4]_7, [0]_7$ when $0<r<8$.

(I'm trying to use this to show that $D_n$ can be generated by two reflections.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well known fact from elementary number theory.
A proof goes somewhat as follows.
By definition of modular arithmetic, we have $r[a]_n = [ra]_n$.
Now suppose that for $0 < r, s < n + 1$ we have $[ra]_n = [sa]_n$. This means that we have $n | (ra - sa)$ or equivalently $n | (r - s)a$. Since n and a are coprime, this implies $n | (r - s)$. This together with the condition $0 < r, s < n + 1$ implies r - s = 0, or equivalently r = s. So the equivalence classes $r[a]_n$ for $0 < r < n + 1$ are pairwise distinct, as desired.